# How to Calculate Days/Time Remaining Based on Percentage of Daily Goal Met

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to create a formula to calculate Time Until Completion (days remaining) based on daily goal completion.

To make this simple here is the scenario:

I want to reach 100 points in 30 days. Each day I will try to collect 3.3 points to reach my 30 day goal. However, each day I will most likely not reach exactly 3.3 points. Some days I might only collect one point and maybe on highly productive days I reach 10 points in a day. These fluctuations in daily points will affect the Time Until Completion. I want to stay on track and know that I'm staying within my 30 day deadline at a glance.

Is there a formula I could use to do this in excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a goal and a timeframe you could calculate the average required (3.3 points), and then track your actual average which is just a formula you apply over the range for the period e.g. `=AVG(B2:B32)`

Simply by comparing the two you'll be able to see your performance versus the required rate.

As you accumulate points you can divide the remaining points by your actual average to determine the estimated days to completion.

To show the days to complete and show 30 if on target in your example just take the required points divided by the average of the points you are achieving.

Comment: I am already tracking my daily (3.3) and final (100) goals using a simple percentage calculation. I'm really just interested in an output that shows the actual Time Until Completion that adjusts as numbers are updated. For example, if all days I entered 3.3 the the Time Until Completion would always read "30" days. But if I enter a 10 for example on a specific day, then I would want the 30 to change to 28 (or whatever the calculation would be). I know this is a bit complex, but I'm hoping it's possible in excel. If not, if someone know of a software program that does this that would be helpful

Comment: That's not too tricky, and is what I said in my answer. To get time to complete just take your average of the points you've accumulated, and the total points you have accumulated. Subtract the total you've accumulated from your final goal and divide it by your average to get an estimated number of days until complete.

Comment: To show the days to complete and show 30 if on target in your example just take the required points divided by the average of the points you are achieving.

Comment: I see, yes, not complicated, just putting in my spreadsheet is confusing me because I need it to update automatically. I will figure it out. Your answer got me on the right track. Much appreciated.

Comment: Best of luck! Please mark the answer as accepted if it has met your requirements.

Comment: And have a look here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculate-the-average-of-a-group-of-numbers-e158ef61-421c-4839-8290-34d7b1e68283